# Set Special Price Programmatically In Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to write a script that will set a special price on a product with a start and an end date. When I run my script it does successfully set the special price, but the start and end date do not populate in the admin panel.

The code I am running is as follows:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(114912);
$product->setSpecialPrice( ($product->getPrice() * .90)   );

$product->setSpecialFromDate('2010-11-01');
$product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true);

$product->setSpecialToDate('2010-11-30');
$product->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(true);

$product->save();
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: i also want to do this. but i don't know where to add this code, please help me

Comment: This code is meant to go into a script that sort of lives outside of Magento. This blog post of mine should help you get this setup. http://overlycaffeinated.com/blog/2011/09/setting-up-your-magento-scripting-environment/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have just tried your code on my catalog and it worked with a little adjustement.

You should pay attention to the loaded store;
it is not allowed to update certain product fields if the ADMIN store is not the currently loaded (`Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);`).

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

...

$product->save();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. +50 for you

Comment: for magento2 -> `$objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->setCurrentStore('admin');`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but have you tried passing a timestamp like from `time()` and leaving out the `setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true)`? That should cause the backend model to reformat it appropriately for you.

Comment: I gave it a try and it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion though.