# Magento: Special Price From Date and To Date change when updating product programmatically

Tags: magento, date

I am using Magento version 1.4.0.1.

I have a product with the following "**Special Price From Date**" and "**Special Price To Date**" (present under 'Prices' tab in product edit page):

> Special Price From Date = 4/7/13 (i.e. April 07, 2013)
>
> Special Price To Date = 7/3/13 (i.e. July 03, 2013)

Then I run the following code to update the product:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->load($productId)
        ->setName('Some new name for the product')
        ->save();
```

The problem is that the special price from date and to date is changed automatically. Now, the special price from and to date become like this:

> Special Price From Date = 7/4/13 (i.e. July 04, 2013)
>
> Special Price To Date = 3/7/13 (i.e. March 07, 2013)

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seem to be a format issue, where it's reversing the day and month  (where 4/7 become 7/4) what happen if you try to reset the date

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
               ->load($productId);

 $product->setName('Some new name for the product')
               ->setSpecialFromDate($product->getSpecialFromDate()) // assuming that this = YYYY-MM-DD
               ->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(true)
               ->setSpecialToDate($product->getSpecialTODate())
               ->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(true)
               ->save();
```

See [Set Special Price Programatically In Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168061/set-special-price-programatically-in-magento)

Comment: Yes, I have already tried this workaround and it works. However, I am trying to find the solution to this problem. Thanks for the reply.